Gram schmidt swapping two vectors
The question has background here but it's really just a linear algebra question.
Suppose I have $B = (b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ vectors and I perform Gram Schmidt process (with no normalization of vector) obtaining $(v_{1},\cdots,v_{n})$.
Now I'd like to swap position $i$ and $i+1$ in $ B = (b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ resulting into performing Gram Schmidt process on $B' = (b_1,\cdots,b_{i+1},b_{i},\cdots, b_n)$. Why does it holds that $||{b'}_{k}^{*}||$ (after the swap) equals $||{b}_{k}^{*}||$ (before the swap) for $k \geq i+2$? The picture is quite clear and intuitive, although I'd like to convince myself through a formal proof as well.
Edit: with the star I mean the ortoghonal vectors given by Gram Schmidt process.

You never defined what the starred vectors are but presumably you meant something like $b_k^* = v_k$.  I suggest you write $B'=BP$ where $P$ is a type 2 elementary matrix and apply QR factorization to $B$ and to $B'$.

@user8675309 Yes I edited it, thanks for the typo. I don't see what QR hint.

Because in the Gram-Schmidt process, the $(i+1)$-th orthonormal vector $b_{i+1}'$ is the normalization of the orthogonal complement of the projection of $b_{i+1}$ to the linear span of $\{b_1, \cdots, b_i\}$. Formally,
$$b_{i+1}'=b_{i+1}-P_{i}(b_{i+1})$$
where $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection to the subspace spanned by $b_1, \cdots, b_i$.
So if we permutate $(b_1, \cdots, b_i)$ (not necessarily swapping the last two, but any permutation) to get $(b_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, b_{\sigma(i)})$, then $b_{i+1}'^*, \cdots, b_n'^*$ are unchanged, since the linear span of $\{b_1, \cdots, b_i\}$ is unchanged. And it's not just the norm, but the vectors themselves are unchanged.

@AlexRavsky Good point. Modified accordingly.

This is clear, thanks. I'm asking in terms of the permuted sum, I'd like to see directly that the two sums are equal, since I tried dozen of times but failed.

For each natural $k\le n$ let $V_k$ be the linear space spanned by the vectors $b_1,\dots,b_k$ and $V_k^\perp$ be the space consisting of all vectors $x\in V_n$ such that $(x,y)=0$ for each $y\in V_k$, that is $(x,b_i)=0$ for each natural $i\le k$. It is easy to show that each vector $x\in V_n$ has a unique decomposition $x=x_k+x^\perp_k$, where $x_k\in V_k$ and $x^\perp_k\in V_k^\perp$.
The Gram Schmidt process yields that $b_k^*=(b_k)^\perp_{k-1}$ for any natural $k$, $2\le k\le n$.
If we swap vectors $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$ then the vector $b_k$ and the spaces $V_{k-1}$ and $V_{k-1}^\perp$ remain the same for any $k\ge i+2$, and so is the vector $b_k^*$.

As answered to Just a user, this is clear, thanks. I'm asking in terms of the permuted sum, I'd like to see directly that the two sums are equal, since I tried dozen of times but failed.
